# QGIS multi-edit issue using relations

Tags: qgis

Using a GeoPackage with this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE species (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
  name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE study_area ( 
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
  geom POLYGON NOT NULL, 
  species_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES species(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
  population INTEGER NOT NULL,
  notes TEXT
);
```

If I try to update "notes" attribute using multi-edit I get a "*Changes to this form will not be saved. 1 field(s) don't meet their constraints.*" warning and I can not update the field value for the 3 polygons.

[image]

Any suggestion? I attach [project+gpkg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PHU01Pupd9h5CCcMi-7V3lTec-eBktzB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Population is `NULL`, but you have `population INTEGER NOT NULL`

Comment: I just updated the picture. If I press on "apply changes" link, I get "Changes to this form will not be saved. 1 field(s) don't meet their constraints." warning.

Comment: Have a look here: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog324/index.html#feature-multiedit-support-for-relation-editor

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it clearly:

> 1 field(s) don't meet their contraint.

For `population`, you have the condition `INTEGER NOT NULL`, but on your screenshot, population is `NULL`. For `id` as well, you have the condition `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL`, but the screenshot shows that it is empty, too.

I tried it with the files you provided: as long as `population` or `id` is `NULL`, you can't save. If you fill in the fields, it will be possible.

There is a problem with the constraint of the autoincrement id that is probably the cause of your headache. In your configuration, `id` is set to editable. Like this, adding new features, autoincrement does not work. Uncheck the box next to `Editable`, fill in a value for `population` and everything will be all right.

[image]

Comment: Since these are existing features, I want to preserve the valid id and population values. I just want to assign a common value in the notes attribute. I understand that multiple editing detects which fields have the same value and which have different values.

Comment: If you unceck `Editable`, your `id` values will be preserved. As long as you don't actively change the values of id or population, they will remain the same. This has nothing to do with constraints, you don't need them. You can simply update your notes field, the rest remains unchanged.

Comment: By the way: what do you mean by "multiple editing"?

Comment: Only your `species_id` has a Relation Reference. So I don't really understand where exactly the problem is. You should never manually edit an autoincrement field with unique constraint (why should you want to do that...?), so unchecking `Editable` preseves you from entering invalid (duplicate) numbers for `id`.

Comment: I wanted to refer to this https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#editing-multiple-fields

Comment: I am fine with uncheck Editable for id field.

Comment: Why don't you use Field calculator for updating notes field?

Comment: Yes, it is a valid alternative in this case. I was trying the QGIS "edit multiple fields" tool because I find it interesting to modify several attributes simultaneously

Comment: Yes, field calculator modifyes severa attributes at once, too.  Together with these restrictions, Field calculator seems easier to work with and you have more control.

Comment: How? I thought field calculator can modify one attribute on multiple features but not multiple attributes on multiple features

Comment: It seems that the "edit multiple fields" tool is not compatible with attributes that have "Enforce unique constraint" constraint checked

Comment: It seems so, indeed. Yes, field calculator can modify one attribute on multiple features. I thought this is what you want, based on your sample data, but probably you have larger data sets and want to be able to update several fields at once.

Comment: If I uncheck the "Enforce unique constraint" for the "id" attribute it seems that works fine. Look at [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZUHFnNT3R9wFoJuvn3z7GvV9yUlOz-X3/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Jorge Rosales](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/35194/jorge-rosales) and [Babel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/88814/babel) these steps solves the problem:

> Uncheck the `Enforce unique constraint` for the `id` attribute

> Uncheck the box next to `Editable`